# Can I pass data from html to js

Tags: javascript, html

hi I am new in web develop so im trying to pass data from (index.html) file to (index.js) file

my html file :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var ipinfo;
      $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io", function (data) {
          $("#details").html( " ,IP: " + data.ip  + "")
      })
     
  </script>
     <p id="details"></p>
```

my js file :

```
var str= document.getElementById('details').innerHTML;
```

also tried :

```
var shdata = document.getElementById('details').value;
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: innerHTML should work.  It sounds like you're not referencing the JS file properly in your HTML.  Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50m3uxe8/)

Comment: i did edit the quastion

Comment: Which seems to work fine still, though it looks like maybe you want to append to the innerHTML/innerText vs replace it entirely.  https://jsfiddle.net/50m3uxe8/2/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, both

```
var str = document.getElementById("details").innerHTML;
```

and

```
var str = document.getElementById("details").innerText;
```

should work.

If not, make sure you referenced the index.js file in your index.html file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var str = document.getElementById("details").innerText;
```

Comment: it worked !! but in my case dosnt! i have edited the quastion

Answer (score 0):

i knew what was wrong its not in the code its because takes time for the html to read the ip or download it so the js gives me null

thanks :P